# Free() is not clearing the prev_in_use bit in glibc

Tags: c, malloc, free, glibc

I am using linux 64 bit having glibc

```
ldd (Ubuntu EGLIBC 2.19-0ubuntu6.15) 2.19
```

This my code

```
int main (int argc , char** argv){    

    char *first , *second;
    first = malloc(16);
    second = malloc(16);

    free(first);
    free(second);    
}
```

The problem is I studied on the internet that when free is called it clears the `prev_in_use` bit of the next chunk and below is the memory region of those 2 chunks after 1st call to `free`.

```
gdb-peda$ x/20gx 0x602010-16
0x602000:   0x0000000000000000  0x0000000000000021
0x602010:   0x0000000000000000  0x0000000000000000
0x602020:   0x0000000000000000  0x0000000000000021
0x602030:   0x0000000000000000  0x0000000000000000
0x602040:   0x0000000000000000  0x0000000000020fc1
0x602050:   0x0000000000000000  0x0000000000000000
```

Now the problem is I studied that the prev_in_use bit of the next adjacent chunk is cleared and the `prev_size` of the next chunk will contain the size of this freed chunk but from the above output neither `prev_in_use` bit is cleared nor size of this chunk is written in next chunk `prev_size` field.

What is the problem ? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: What were the values of the `first` and `second` pointers?

Comment: first = 0x602010 , second = 0x602030. The above output is of ldd (Ubuntu EGLIBC 2.19-0ubuntu6.15) 2.19 but same thing is also happeining ldd (Debian GLIBC 2.36-9+deb12u3) 2.36.
I changed code and added
memset(first , 'A' , 16);
memset(second , 'B' 16);
 and here is the output after first free call
0x602000: 0x0000000000000000 0x0000000000000021
0x602010: 0x0000000000000000 0x4141414141414141
0x602020: 0x0000000000000000 0x0000000000000021
0x602030: 0x4242424242424242 0x4242424242424242
0x602040: 0x0000000000000000 0x0000000000020fc1

Comment: *"The problem is I studied on the internet"* - study the source code of the library if you want do dive into details, not **"the internet"**.

Comment: `/* Size of the chunk below P.  Only valid if !prev_inuse (P).  */
#define prev_size(p) ((p)->mchunk_prev_size)`

Comment: I am studying the soure code and it says clear_inuse_bit_at_offset(nextchunk, 0);
when next chunk is not top and is in used. but from the output it is not as expected as wriiten in source code

Comment: shouldn't it clear the prev_in_use bit ?

Comment: @MuhammadJamshaid when a comment asks for information, please [edit] the question and put all information **into the question**.

Answer (score 2):

The thing is that glibc is a lil' bit more complicated than that. It uses several methods to store free chunks. In the example you are showing, because of the size of the chunks that you are using, they are going to the tcache.

The glibc has the problem that its malloc implementation (the ptmalloc2 algorithm) varies a lot between versions. You should have included the glibc version you are using. Either way, assuming your ubuntu is up to date you probably are using glibc 2.35. You can see below the code for `_int_free()`, which is the one that implements free()'s main functionality.

```c
static void
_int_free (mstate av, mchunkptr p, int have_lock)
{
  // [... declaration of variables and a couple of security checks]

#if USE_TCACHE
  {
    size_t tc_idx = csize2tidx (size);
    if (tcache != NULL && tc_idx < mp_.tcache_bins)
      {

    // [... another security check]

    if (tcache->counts[tc_idx] < mp_.tcache_count)
      {
        tcache_put (p, tc_idx);
        return;
      }
      }
  }
#endif
```

Immediately after a few superficial checks the function sees if that chunk is of a size that would make it eligible to be placed in the tcache. This is done with csize2tidx (which means "chunk size to tcache index"), this is because the tcache has several bins, one for a different chunk size, so what this macro does is take a size and tell the index of the tcache bin that size corresponds, then we check if that index does actually exist, which effectively sets a limit on the size a chunk may have before being put in the tcache, this limit is, in x64 and with a typical configuration, 1024.

Now the important part, you can see that if the chunk has an appropriate size and its tcache bin isn't full (a tcache bin is full with 7 chunks), the chunks is placed there and the prev_inuse bit of the next contiguous chunks never gets updated.

This is because tcache'd chunks aren't supposed to be merged with other chunks so, in order to prevent them from being consolidated when a contiguous chunk is free'd, they are always marked in use.

Comment: "You should have included the glibc version" -- OP said: `EGLIBC 2.19` right _there_.

Comment: @EmployedRussian oh right, initially I thought that was just the output from `uname -a` and didn't analyze it properly, also because 2.19 would have been a glibc version from MANY years ago and I simply discarded it as a possible version. Now, the thing is that OP wasn't accurate when saying that he is using glibc when that message actually says EGLIBC, so it isn't GLibC, and that contributed to my cognitive dissonance.

Comment: In any case my explanation probably still holds: the chunks are going to a different cache. I have no experience with EGLibC whatsoever, but I guess it probably doesn't have a tcache (it is a library for embedded systems), so they must be going to a fastbin or equivalent.